# How to change class name of all elements without iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM structure like this: (using jQuery)

```
<div class="test page-1">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-2">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-3">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-4">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-5">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-6">some code and more dom</div>
<div class="test page-7">some code and more dom</div>

and few more ....
```

Now, how can I increase the number suffixing classes like `page-1, page-2` etc. by `n (e.g. by 1)` so that resulting class becomes `page-2, page-3` etc. ?

i.e. only number of class `page-1` will increase and `page-1` class becomes `page-2`

One way is to iterate through all elements using class `test` and remove the class and add the new one.

Is there a better way to achieve this for more performance?

*The use case is where I have to insert page in between the divs so the inserted page becomes the current page and page's number after that will increase by 1.*

Comment: how many __divs__ approximately will your page have? coz I think this is a case of premature optimization!

Comment: It can have more than 100, though I have a plan to load/unload dom elements, but for now this is the situation.

Comment: No, you cannot change them without iterating the elements. However, you should not use classes to number your elements anyway. What do you need them for?

Comment: @Bergi I need them for page numbering. The other way would be to use `data` attribute, but `data` attribute selection is slower than `class` selector.

Comment: @Deepak - You don't need to select based on the `data-` attribute anyway, you can still select on `.test` and only change the  `data-` attribute..

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra What if I want to select on page number basis?

Comment: @deepak - You've got a point there, but see LeGEC's answer which might help you do it without having to save anything in classes or `data-` attributes at all.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra Yes LeGEC's is making a very good point.

Comment: @deepak: Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or `:nth-child()` for selection, and CSS counters for numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. Even if you wanted to add the same class to all elements, the loop would be hidden inside the `$('.test').addClass('myClass')` call.

You could use a `data-page` attribute, use jQuery's `.data()` function, or not add anything and use `$(this).index()` or the loop counter to have a page number :

```
 $('.test').each(function(i) {
      // i is the page number ...
 });

 // accessing the i-th element :
 $('.test')[i];
```

Comment: hmmm I think `i+1` would be the page number in my case. Seems I can workout something with this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$("[class*='page-']").each(function(){
    var 
    newClass,
    classParts,
    currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
    classParts = currentClass.split('-');
    newClass = classParts[0] +'-'+ (parseInt(classParts[1])+1);
    $(this).attr('class', newClass)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".test").each(function(index, element) {
     var classes = $(this).attr("class");
     var splitted = classes.split("-")[1];
     classes = classes.replace(splitted,String(parseInt(splitted)+1));
     $(this).removeAttr('class').addClass(classes);
});
```

Comment: "Without iteration", you have an each in your answer... ( PS: I still think it's best to iterate with an each for this )